# argument "male" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, function, arguments

I'm trying to create a function that performs calculations based off of a patient's information. However, I keep getting the same error message that says "Error in SMARTRISK(PATIENT1): argument "male" is missing, with no default".
Here is the function:

```
SMARTRISK=function(age,male,smoker,systolic,diabetic,CAD,CVD,AAA,PAD,yrs,HDL,
                   TCHOL,eGFR,loghsCRP)
{
  SMARTRISK=(-0.0850*age)+(0.00105*(age^2))+(0.156*male)+(0.262*smoker)+
    (0.00429*systolic)+(0.223*diabetic)+(0.140*CAD)+(0.406*CVD)+(0.558*AAA)+
    (0.283*PAD)+(0.0229*yrs)-(0.426*HDL)+(0.0959*TCHOL)-(0.0532*eGFR)+
    (0.000306*(eGFR^2))+(0.139*loghsCRP)
  return(SMARTRISK) #return the SMARTRISK linear predictor as an output of the function
}
```

Then I initiated the following data frame:

```
age=65
male=0
smoker=1
systolic=160
diabetic=1
CAD=0
CVD=0
AAA=0
PAD=1
yrs=12
HDL=2
TCHOL=4
eGFR=100
loghsCRP=1
PATIENT1=data.frame(age,male,smoker,systolic,diabetic,CAD,CVD,AAA,PAD,yrs,HDL,
                    TCHOL,eGFR,loghsCRP)
```

And here is the final calculation I'm trying to perform:

```
(1-(0.81066^(exp(SMARTRISK(PATIENT1))+2.099)))*100
```

I am not understanding why things are getting caught up at "male". I have also tried print(male) and print(male)==1 within the function, but keep getting the same results. Why would it not understand the argument "male" but understand the "age" argument?

Comment: To answer your question directly, it's because you are creating a function with many arguments (all of which expect vectors), but you are feeding it just one, a data frame. The quickest way to fix is to change your function definition to only be one argument - a data frame, and to then change the function body to indicate you want to use a variable within that data frame (`mydf[["myvar"]]`).

Comment: But beyond that, there's a workflow problem here. If you have created a model, you can save the fit of that model as its own object, and use `predict()` to apply that model onto new data. You don't actually need to design a function with all the parameters and coefficients of that model.

Comment: @Phil Thank you! I'm doing this as part of a course and we're only supposed to use topics we've learned up until now (it's only like the third week). As we haven't learned the `predict()` function, I'll have to focus on your first comment for now.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same thing. I had set up mine a bit differently
Data= data.frame('age',.....)
then
SMARTRISK= function(Data)
and the long formula that goes under it
then for the patient data, I did
PATIENT1= data.frame(65,....)
and got my answer that way